# Ghost blog check if user is logged in with embed in blog post

Tags: ghost-blog

I am embedding some html into my blog post.
I only want to show it if the user is not logged in.
How can I wrap this html area in if statements to check if the user is logged in or not.

```
{{#if access}}
    <p>Thanks for being a member...</p>
  {{else}}
    <p>You need to become a member in order to read this post... </p>
  {{/if}}
```

or

```
{{#if @member}}
  <p>Thanks for becoming a member </p>
{{else}}
  <p>You should totally sign up... </p>
{{/if}}
```

How can I put this in a html card?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show an access message then the first one is the correct option. But if you want to how the post to subscribed members then this is the correct format.

```
    {{#if access}}
            {{!-- if the user has access to this post, show it to them --}
                <section>
                    <div>
                        {{content}}
                    </div>
                </section>

            {{else}}
            {{!-- if the user does not have access, show them an upgrade CTA --}}
           
            <p>You don't have access to this post on <strong>{{@site.title}}</strong> at the moment, but if you upgrade your account you'll be able to see the whole thing, as well as all the other posts in the archive! Subscribing only takes a few seconds and will give you immediate access.</p>

     {{/if}}
```

Comment: This cannot work from the html block in the editor right? It has to be put in the theme code?

Comment: Yes. You have to include it in your theme.

Comment: It is because ghost engine will inject content from the backend.